# Pass reference of object to a new Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, parameterized

I have an object that contains a very large 3D-array of doubles and I need to start a new thread that need the data of this array, so I will either need to start a new thread passing the object (which contains a whole lot of other data too) to the new thread or I just pass the 3D-array to the new thread.
For the first solution I would simply do the following:

```
MyClass
{
    ...
    public double[,,] _data = new double[x,y,z];
    ...
}

MyMethod(object MyObject)
{
    //do stuff with (MyObject as MyClass)
}

MyClass _newObject = new MyClass();

Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyMethod));
thread.Start(_newObject);
```

My question now: As I pass the object `_newObject` to the new thread, is that object sent to the thread by reference or is the object copied and the copy used by the new thread? The problem is that the object contains data of around 300MB and it would be almost impossible if copies are used since I need to start around 10 threads that need to use data of that object.

Comment: Well I read two thick books about C# and did reasearch on the internet but I couldn't find anything. I don't just ask questions without trying to find it out on my own first. The books didn't cover the `ParameterizedThreadStart` well enough to explain how data is passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reference.

If you change the data in your thread it will change the original data you put in. Same applies if you change the data outside the thread your thread will see the modified data.

You need proper locking mechanisms so that it will not collide when accessing the data from multiple threads.

Comment: I guess I will read about locking mechanisms. It will make more sense than running the threads one after another instead...

Comment: Do I also need a locking mechanism if I simply read the data? The thread method will never change data, only do calculations with it.

Comment: You need locking if you change the data somewhere at the same time. If you ONLY read from the data and never change it at the same time you don't need locking.

Comment: Thanks, that is very important to me. I will only read the data.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise it's send by *reference copy*.

Since this is a `reference type`, only a *reference* is copied in this case, and not all data.

That's why you have to care about `locking mechanisms` in cases where more then one `thread` accesses the data this object refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure, however, if I understand what exactly you mean, maybe a small code sample could help me to understand...

Comment: I mean that what you copy 4byte (for 32 bit machines) pointer, and nothing else. Don't warry about 300MB.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will now need to look into locking mechanisms if I access the data. As I told BlueM I will never change the data of the object, only use it for calculations, do I need to care about locking it then?

Comment: @phil13131: if this is only about reading static values (in terms of the values say are just set of numbers), and no calculation, or file system aceess, or **any** other stuff happens during the access to that information, you can avoid carring about locking.

Comment: Yes thanks, I tried to find out about this topic for around one hour now, but I couldn't find a clear answer, not even within any of my books. I don't understand why I got a vote down for this question.

Answer (score 1):

10 thread ? how do you plan to maintain the data integrity of the _newObject ?
Saying that copies will not be passed, only the reference will be used.
If you going to call the method MyMethod(object MyObject) in 10 different threads
will the MyObject be different objects ?? if not you are better off refractoring the method.

 Also you should remember that a thread is just a liner set of instructions to be executed.
So just because of using multiple threads your object size will not increase in the memory. 

 the very advantage of multi threading is to make use of different threads to process your instructions, and does not make copies of objects.

Comment: No it is the same object. I need to do many calculations at the same time but in a different way. I guess I can change the code such that the calculations are done one after another such that only one thread is carried out at the same time.

Comment: again when one thread waits for the previous thread to work on the same object, then whats the use of threading ??

Comment: That was my question. After all if you pass data to a method, that data is copied, I thought if I pass an object to a new thread that data might also be copied.

Comment: No data will not be copied, it will be passed as reference by default and you need to make the method thread safe also. And with the sample you have posted, I don't see any advantage, because for these 10 threads will anyway need to be executed after one another.Unless ofcourse you are doing someother operation in the main thread while waiting for these threads to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your MyClass is a class, then the reference of the object is only passed to the new thread, since it is a reference type([read more on reference types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)), i would also suggest that you use a lock in order avoid deadlock issues you can do that simply by using the [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword

Comment: According to BlueM I don't need to lock the data, as I only access the data by reading it to do calculations with it and never change it within the thread.

Comment: yes that is correct, as long as you are not changing the object **at the same time on any thread, including the UI one**, in case you are changing it then you need to get a lock before doing that