# Pass Parameters by Value(not reference) through ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm trying to pass parameters(copy not ref) to thread through the following:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
thread.start(concurrentQueueObj);
```

But I observed that it is being passed by reference. Same is answered by 'BlueM' in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298801/pass-reference-of-object-to-a-new-thread)

Any idea how to pass parameters by copy to a thread? I'd appreciate some help.

**Edit**: I just want that thread receives a copy of parameters.So that if main thread changes concurrentQueueObj, it has no effect on parameters of worker thread.

Comment: "But I observed that it is being passed by reference." No, the reference is being passed by value. If you want to create a deep copy of the object, you'll need to do that yourself. But it's worth really making sure you understand the difference between passing a reference by value, and pass-by-reference... otherwise you'll have problems understanding what happens when you pass a reference type variable by reference.

Comment: Passing *a* reference and passing *by* reference are two different things. In this case, you're passing *a* reference, but it is passed *by* value. It's a hard topic to get to grips with, I'll see if I can find a fitting article, think Jon Skeet has written something about this at one time. Here's one - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html - though not the one I seem to remember.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You just made my brain explode :)

Comment: If you could pass a concurrentQueue by value it wouldn't have to be concurrent.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Actually the behavior of concurrentQueue is not required by this thread. the behavior of concurrentQueue is required for some other Tasks.

Comment: Then maybe change that. It always pays to be clear about the intent of code, and to not give of false signals.

Comment: @MickyD: Any day your brain explodes with new knowledge is a good day in my book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: I just want that thread receives a copy of parameters.So that if main thread changes concurrentQueueObj, it has no effect on parameters of worker thread.

If the main thread does

```
thread.start(concurrentQueueObj);
concurrentQueueObj = null;
```

then your Thread code will not notice a thing.

If however it does something like

```
thread.start(concurrentQueueObj);
concurrentQueueObj.Enqueue(someData);
```

then of course `someData` will be available inside the thread. Which is really the point of a concurrent collection.

Comment: Actually the behavior of concurrentQueue is not required by this thread. the behavior of concurrentQueue is required for some other Tasks.

Comment: Then be clearer: what is the queue for? Could it be a List<>?

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you're asking though you're using the wrong words for it.

You're not passing the `concurrentQueueObj` variable *by reference*, you're passing the *value* of the `concurrentQueueObj` variable which *is* a reference.

In short, you're passing *a* reference, not *by* reference.

If you want to read more about this topic I'm sure you can find many articles on the internet, as well as quality questions and answers here on Stack Overflow. You could start by reading Jon Skeets article on [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Passing *by* reference would use the `ref` or `out` keywords, and in later versions of C#, the `in` keyword.

However, the question as I understand it is this:

> Can I pass a copy of the `concurrentQueueObj` object to the thread so that if it or I (the code that starts the thread) modifies this object afterward, this won't *leak* into different threads?

And the answer, in the general sense, is both a no and a yes.

There is nothing *general* built into the C# programming language or the .NET runtime and library platform that *generally* solves this.

However, what you can do is make a copy yourself, and pass that in. Exactly how you would do that depends entirely on the type of the object being passed in. If, for instance, it was a `List<T>`, you could simply call `.ToList()` on it and you would get a new list.

You would *not*, however, get a copy of all the objects *inside* the list. Those would still be shared between the original list and the copy.

The only "copy method" that is 100% foolproof is to create a deep copy of the object, which means you clone/copy *every* object contained therein.

There are numerous data structures, both built into .NET and available as NuGet packages, that aim to solve parts of this problem in different ways, such as immutable data structures and collections, and so on. Which of these would be applicable to your scenario depends on the type of that variable.

---

If you want to read more about passing *a* reference vs. *by* reference, in .NET and C# there are two axes to this problem:

- Value types (values)
- Reference types (references, though the value of a reference variable, is the reference)

And:

- Passing *by* reference
- Passing *by* value

You have all combinations of these two axes combined so if you want to learn more about this, be sure to learn what it means to:

- **Passing a value type by value**

  which is a copy
- **Passing a value type by reference**

  which is a reference, pointer, to the variable holding the value
  type
- **Passing a reference type by value**

  which is a copy of the reference, but not the object it refers to
- **Passing a reference type by reference**

  which is a reference to the variable holding the reference type